# Windows Registry key for "check whether IE is the default browser"?

Tags: internet-explorer, default, registry

In IE under Tools-> Internet Options -> Programs there's a checkbox labelled "Tell me if Internet Explorer is not the default web browser." What's the registry key that corresponds to this checkbox? The reason I ask is that I want to suppress this check programmatically.

Clarification: I don't want to find out the default browser, I want to stop IE checking if it *is* the default browser when it starts up.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's been answered in various ways over the web and here; here's one question which covers it; [Windows RegKey - Default Browser Application Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813058/windows-regkey-default-browser-application-path). Then it's just checking if the path is the iexplore.exe path.

**Update:** I just checked what the key is that is modified when you deselect and reselect the "check default browser" option.

When you deselect it, the value
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Check_Associations` is created, a `REG_SZ` containing the string "no".

When you reselect it, `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Check_Associations` is altered to "yes".

So: if `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Check_Associations` does not exist or is "yes", it will check. To avoid that check (potentially user-unfriendly behaviour - use with care - create as "no" or set to "no" the value `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Check_Associations`.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough; I don't want to find the default browser, I want to stop IE checking if it is the default browser. I'll add this clarification to the question.

Comment: Ah. I don't know and am not running Windows just at the moment, but it will be somewhere in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer`. Look through there and see if you can spot it. "Check if default" or something like that.

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry, I thought that had answered you enough. Just checked which precise value it is (Regshot is useful that way) and updated the answer.

Comment: That was it! Thanks, I'll award the bounty when OS lets me. I looked inside the "Main" key, but never guessed that "Check_Associations" was the culprit. Finding out about regshot was worth 50 rep all by itself; thanks for that tip too!

Comment: Have just tried this and the HKCU setting was "no". However, this article (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-constant-pop-up-asking-if/dceb54dd-fe3d-4fde-9b05-8f09186fb8ab) says to use the same key on HKLM and that then does the trick :)

Answer (score 8):

For those trying to defeat corporate group policy, this does the trick in one command

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /f /v "Check_Associations" /d "no" /t REG_SZ
```

Comment: PowerShell equivalent: `Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main' -Name Check_Associations -Value 'no'`

Answer (score 3):

There are two keys:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.htm`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.html`

Change the Default Key value to: `htmlfile` or `ChromeHTML`

Not sure about Firefox, but if you set it here, you will not be asked.