# How to change the default browser in Windows?

Tags: c#, browser, registry, defaults, default-browser

I have created a simple browser in c# for a couple family members. I want to set it as the default browser either from an installer or from the program. I want to do the same thing as Chrome or Firefox does when it asks you if you want to set it as default. I can set up command line processing, all I need to know is how to how to set the default browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate (see the answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222367/windows-registry-key-for-check-whether-ie-is-the-default-browser

Comment: May be not exactly, OP requires programmatic approach.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/configuration/how-can-i-configure-the-default-internet-browser- has the information you want. So you can check these entries at startup and they are not what you want you can set them!

Having created your own browser I assume you are able to use the Microsoft.Win32.Registry and translate this to code on your own.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can change it using registry entries as @Mattias told you. But it is a really bad idea , if you do that you are hurting user experience.

In a corporate environment, domain policies already have support to make this things.

You also can establish local (nor domain) policies using GPedit.msc. Change registry entries or use gpedit.msc , any way don't hurt UX even in your family this is awfull for affected people. Anybody must be free tho choose the browser they want, even a bad browser.

Comment: This is just a favor for a couple of family members

Comment: You also can stablish local policies using GPedit.msc. Change registry entries or use gpedit.msc , any way don't hurt UX even in your family this is awfull for affected people. Anybody must be free tho choose the browser they want, even a bad browser.