# Test if filetype has default application

Tags: actionscript-3, file, air, adobe

**Background:** I have a readme file which is a `.html` file.

I am using `_file.openWithDefaultApplication()` to open this up in the browser.
This works perfectly and I thought was foolproof. Problem I have is it seems I have a better fool for a co-worker who was testing my application.

His Windows PC had **NO** default application set for a `.html` file so when he selected a default application, he choosen "notepad".. as you might have guessed, reading a .html in notepad was useless but Windows 8 choosen this as the default from that point onwards.

**Question 1** Can I test if the application has a default application, so I can warn someone to open a .html file in a browser.

**Question 2** Can I choose to ignore the default application if it is not a browser or somehow remove the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find anything that lets you get the path to the browser executable directly. But if you are down with writing a native extension, you can probe the Windows Registry to get the path. Compare it against a known whitelist of popular browsers.

The Registry keys to inspect for a documented at [Windows RegKey - Default Browser Application Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813058/windows-regkey-default-browser-application-path) and at [How to determine the Windows default browser (at the top of the start menu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177957/how-to-determine-the-windows-default-browser-at-the-top-of-the-start-menu)

Writing native extensions is a bit of a hassle, and I've never written one for Windows desktop. It might be more trouble than you've bargained for.

.p

Comment: Yes, it is far too much trouble for such a small application. I am going to chalk this problem down to user error/computer setup. It doesn't technically fix problem, but I'm going to give you the tick anyway. :D Enjoy.