# Issues about opening the default browser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to open an webpage from a VB.NET application using the default browser (Chrome in my case).

I use this code:

```
Dim BrowserRegistryString As String = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("\http\shell\open\command\").GetValue("").ToString
Dim DefaultBrowserPath As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(BrowserRegistryString, "(\"".*?\"")").Captures(0).ToString
Process.Start(DefaultBrowserPath, "http://www.example.com")
```

It works pretty well except it opens the website in Microsoft Edge altough if i use "start http://www.example.com" in the shell, it opens the site in Chrome.
Chrome is set to be my default browser (from Windows 10 Configuration Pannel), so...

...where that mistery came from?

Comment: If you want to open the default WebBrowser, why not just `Process.Start("http://www.example.com")`?

Comment: Because it doesn't work. I got this exception : "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : 'File not found'

Comment: What .Net version are you using? + Have you tried running the app elevated? Or add the `runas` verb?

Comment: I used .NET 5.0
I don't know what did you mean by "running the app elevated" and "add the runas verb". :/

Comment: In any.Net Core application (or derived from .Net Core, as .Net 5) , [UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) is  `false`, while in .Net Framework is `true`. So you need to set it to `true` using the `Process.ProcessStartInfo`. -- An *elevated* application is run with admin rights, same as using the [runas verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verbs), to ask the user to grant admin rights to the calling Process.

Comment: I tried this following you previous comment but it opens Edge too:

`Dim BrowserRegistryString As String = My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("\http\shell\open\command\").GetValue("").ToString
Dim DefaultBrowserPath As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(BrowserRegistryString, "(\"".*?\"")").Captures(0).ToString
Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
p.FileName = DefaultBrowserPath
p.Arguments = url_ugc_online
Process.Start(p)`

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813058/windows-regkey-default-browser-application-path

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i've used and it works like a charm.
I guess there is better way to extract the default browser path without the parameters...

```
Public Function GetDefaultBrowser() As String
        Dim strDefaultBrowserPathTemp As String
        Dim intPosDefaultBrowserFileExtension As Int16
        Using userChoiceKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice")
            If userChoiceKey IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim progIdValue As Object = userChoiceKey.GetValue("Progid")
                If progIdValue IsNot Nothing Then
                    strDefaultBrowserPathTemp = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & userChoiceKey.GetValue("Progid") & "\shell\open\command", "", Nothing).ToString
                    intPosDefaultBrowserFileExtension = strDefaultBrowserPathTemp.IndexOf(".exe" & Chr(34))
                    Return Left(strDefaultBrowserPathTemp, intPosDefaultBrowserFileExtension + Len(".exe" & Chr(34)))
                End If
            End If
        End Using
End Function
```